# My jquery isn't getting a value back with val() when the selector is working

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I am trying to create a function in my customizer on wordpress to display certain fields but I keep getting back undefined when everything seems to be aligned in my JS file correctly.

```
function cta() {
        //Selector for the entire radio area that "should return" the value (either "one" or "two")
        var ctaOptions = $("input[name='_customize-radio-cta-type']");

        //The ID selector for option one to check if this field is "checked"
        var ctaOne  = $('#_customize-input-cta-type-radio-one');

        //The ID selector for option Two to check if this field is "checked"
        var ctaTwo = $('#_customize-input-cta-type-radio-two');

        //This console log always returns undefined, but returns the element without the .val()
        console.log(ctaOptions.val());

        //This always returns false even when I can see in the inspector this element is checked="checked"
        console.log(ctaTwo.is(':checked'));

        if(ctaOne.is(':checked')) {
            $('#customize-control-button-two-label').addClass('hidden');
        }
        else if(ctaTwo.is(':checked')) {
            $('#customize-control-button-two-label').removeClass('hidden');
        }
    }
```

I am using an unscores boilerplate for my wordpress theme, but unsure if that has anything to do with the conflict in the javascript. I have also confirmed that the ID's are correct using the inspector, just for some reason it breaks when trying to get is checked or the values.

Here is the HTML of the area I am referring to

```
<li id="customize-control-cta-type" class="customize-control customize-control-radio" style="display: list-item;">
   <span class="customize-control-title">Call To Action buttons on banner</span>
   <div class="customize-control-notifications-container" style="display: none;"> 
     <ul></ul>
   </div>
   <span id="_customize-description-cta-type" class="description customize- 
    control-description">How many buttons do you want?
   </span>
                
   <span class="customize-inside-control-row">
    <input id="_customize-input-cta-type-radio-one" type="radio" aria- 
     describedby="_customize-description-cta-type" value="one" name="_customize- 
     radio-cta-type" data-customize-setting-link="cta-type">
    <label for="_customize-input-cta-type-radio-one">one</label>
   </span>
   <span class="customize-inside-control-row">
    <input id="_customize-input-cta-type-radio-two" type="radio" aria- 
     describedby="_customize-description-cta-type" value="two" name="_customize- 
     radio-cta-type" data-customize-setting-link="cta-type" checked="checked">
    <label for="_customize-input-cta-type-radio-two">two</label>
   </span>
</li>
```

Comment: `This console log always returns undefined, but returns the element without the .val()` Are you sure that's the case? A jQuery selector always returns an object even if no element was found. Try checking `console.log(ctaOptions.length)` to see if any elements were actually found. If the output is `0`, your problem is an invalid selector. Without a HTML sample to recreate the issue, we can't really help any further than that

Comment: Can you [edit] your question include the section of HTML that this is being applied to? As Rory says, we can't really help with why it can't find an element when we can't see what you have :)

Comment: I have just your response. And you are right. I am getting a length of 0. I will figure out this selector problem.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan I have added in my HTML to maybe be able to give more insight.

Comment: Also there are two radio. Using `val()` will only ever give value of the first in collection . You aren't considering which one is checked

Comment: @charlietfl it appears my problem is further back at the selector and isn't returning anything because they all appear to have a .length of 0.

Comment: If the line breaks are really in the HTML attribute values, that's your problem. Remove them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have came to the conclusion that my problem wasn't the javascript, it was down to the root of the selector. I still haven't been able to fix it, but my question is unanswerable as it wasn't the problem. Thank you for the feedback.

**Edit 1:**
PROBLEM FOUND! It wasn't my JS that was the problem at all. It was the way i brought in the previous file. I needed to enqueue a JavaScript file to customize_controls_enqueue_scripts. When I took my script and added it to a new JS file and put the below code into my customize.php

```
function theme_slug_customizer_controls() {
    wp_enqueue_script( 'theme-customizer-controls', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/customize-controls.js', array( 'jquery' ), '20170412', true );
}
add_action( 'customize_controls_enqueue_scripts', 'theme_customizer_controls' );
```

Comment: Good luck on fixing it!

Comment: Thank you, I appreciate your help!

Answer (score 1):

Try setting up a `setTimeout(function()` around your current js function, it might be that your js script is loaded before the php actually populate the input.

```
$( document ).ready( function () {
setTimeout( function () {

//Your function goes here...

}, 1);
} );
```

**EDIT 1:** Regarding your last comment. If the input value is intended to be fetch from a user input then you should add an event listener. something like this...

```
$('#_customize-input-cta-type-radio-two, input[name="_customize-radio-cta-type"], #_customize-input-cta-type-radio-two').change(function(){

});
```

Comment: This is a really ugly hack. There are better approaches to managing dynamically inserted elements

Comment: This makes sense. I tried to remove the code from the function and it should just load on page refresh. and every time I click the radio buttons it refreshes the page. Which could very well mean that the PHP loads after the JS.

Comment: Hey @charlietfl , that is true, it's an uggly hack that works most of the time. this is mostly to debug, if it ends up working then we know where the problem is coming from and we can act on it.

Comment: hey @davidb3rn you need to have the script running onclick and on pageload then, your problem is probably coming from that. You're currently only runing the script on page load, but not on event.

Comment: In regards to your last comment, see edit 1